# Assign number of occurence of ID for every row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, powerbi

I need to add a column to table in which will be tracked number of occurrence of ID to given date (there are about 500 of IDs). The table is ordered by date. The ID can appear only once per day.

example of the table

[image]

Comment: please post your attempt in the question.

Comment: Do you mean add the column to a query result or add the column to the table with the expectation that it will be maintained going forward?

Comment: Why do you need to store this in the table when it can be calculated at any time? Not only does storing this information waste space, but think of all the work you'll have maintaining this data - what happens, say, when the first two rows in your image are deleted?

Comment: I need it in PowerBI so I can track averages and other values for last 5/10/15 occurrences. It is not working with Date because occurances are irregular. Unfortunately, I didn't find a way how to do it in PowerBI. Anyway the table is not that big (around 22 000 of rows) and should not grow that much. And there is no reason to delete first two rows.

Comment: PowerBI can only look directly at a table? It can't look at a view, or get its data using a query, or connecting to a stored procedure? Also deletes can happen for reasons other than manually looking at a row and saying "delete that one." Rollbacks, cascade, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the number of occurence, you can use windowing function rank over partition by.  See below.

```
select [date],
        [id],
        rank() 
         over (partition by [id] order by [date]) 
         as  occurence
 from yourTable;
```